# Incluir opciones en la barra de navegacion de acuerdo al grupo al que pertenece el usuario logeado

Tags: html, css, django

estoy haciendo una pagina web en django, y quiero que cuando se logea un usuario perteneciente a cierto grupo ("Basan") le aparezca un nueva opción en la barra de navegación.

Estuve buscando y debería funcionar incluyendo lo siguiente en la plantilla base donde esta la barra de navegación:

{% if "Basan" in request.user.groups.all %}

Opción adicional

{% endif %}

pero al parecer el "request.user.groups.all" no devuelve string por lo que al comparar no son iguales.
Si uso un "for" para comprobar si me esta retornando los grupos, si funciona.
Pero nunca entra en el "if".

{% for group in request.user.groups.all %}

{{group}}

```
{% if 'Basan' == group %} 
        <li> <a href="{% url 'Mas' %}">Opcion Adicional</a>  </li>
        <li><a href="#">Opción adicional 2</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Ya que es un archivo html no puedo usar el metodo str(group) para convertir a string lo que devuelve el request.user.groups.all, esto si funciona en un view.py

El codigo de la barra que tengo es el siguiente:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark py-lg-4" id="mainNav">
<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand text-uppercase text-expanded font-weight-bold d-lg-none" href="{% url 'Inicio' %}">Gestión de Pedidos</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
    
           
      <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == '/' %} active {% endif %} px-lg-4">
        <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="{% url 'Inicio' %}">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == '/servicios/' %} active {% endif %} px-lg-4">
        <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="{% url 'Servicios' %}">Servicios</a>
      </li> 
    {% if 'Basan' in request.user.groups.all %}
        <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == '/mas/' %} active {% endif %}px-lg-4">
          <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="{% url 'Mas' %}">Mas</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Opción 2</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Por favor me podrían decir como podría incluir estas opciones adicionales en la barra de navegación según el grupo al que pertenece un usuario logeado?

Muchas gracias.